# removing one route from a resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I created an app and rails created `resources :results`

I created the following custom route which works

```
match '/final',  :to => 'results#index'
```

however, due to the `resources :results` the user can still type in `www.domainname.com/results` into a browser and see the same page as `/final`

What can I do to stop someone from typing in www.domainame.com/results

For example, if someone understands rails set up they can see a page I don't want them to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd add an exception for that case:

```
resources :results, :except => :index
```

Comment: I just put it in exactly like that in the routes.rb file?